# Issue using Python3 multiprocessing to scan networks concurrently

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, typeerror

Related to my original question here: [Python3 threading, trying to ping multiple IPs/test port simultaineously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582179/python3-threading-trying-to-ping-multiple-ips-test-port-simultaineously)

Basically, I've expanded on the original requirements and made this object-oriented. So I have a Client class with a client name, a location, and a network cidr. My port_test.py script queries a database for clients, initiates a client object, and calls it's `display_results` method, which defines a ThreadPool and calls `scan_network`, which scans IP ranges for a certain port defined in my config file.

I think I have this close to working, but I get this error calling `range(len(all_hosts))` (see code below): `TypeError: object of type 'IPv4Address' has no len()`

I understand the error, I just don't understand why I'm getting it. This worked before I made the class, and I don't see why it doesn't work now.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT: See my answer for working code**

port_test.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

# Import modules
import mysql.connector
import logging
import configparser
import coloredlogs
from Client import Client

#logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s',level=logging.INFO)


coloredlogs.install(level='DEBUG')
coloredlogs.DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s -- %(message)s'


# read from the config file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
db=config['mysql']
net=config['network']
port = int(net['port'])

# create the connection, connect, and setup the query
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=db['host'], user=db['user'], database=db['database'], password=db['password'])
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("select c.client_name as name, l.location_name as location, fw.net_cidr as cidr "
        "from firewalls fw "
            "left join clients c on c.id = fw.client_id "
            "left join locations l on l.id = fw.location_id "
                "where fw.net_cidr <> '' and c.active = '1' and fw.active = '1'")

cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()

for (name, location, cidr) in results:
    client_obj = Client(name, location, cidr)
    net_addr = str(cidr)
    client_obj.display_results(net_addr)

# close the database connection

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Client.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

# Client.py
import logging
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import configparser
import coloredlogs
import ipaddress
import socket
import subprocess

# read from the config file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
net=config['network']
port = int(net['port'])

class Client:
    def __init__(self, name, location, net_cidr):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.net_cidr = net_cidr

    def display_results(self, net_addr):
    # execute and display the results
            logging.info("{} -> {} ---> {} ".format(self.name, self.location, self.net_cidr))
            try:
                ip_net = ipaddress.ip_network(net_addr)
                # Get all hosts on that network
                all_hosts = list(ip_net.hosts())

                # make a pool of workers
                pool = ThreadPool(16)

                # ping the cidrs in their own thread
                pool.map(self.scan_network, all_hosts)
                pool.close()
                pool.join()

            except ValueError as e:
                logging.warning(e)

    def scan_network(self, all_hosts):
        logging.info("List Length: " + str(len(all_hosts)))
        try:
            for i in range(len(all_hosts)):
                # For each IP address in the subnet, test to see if port 3389 is open
                sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                sock.settimeout(.25)
                result = sock.connect_ex((str(all_hosts[i]),port))
                if result == 0:
                    logging.info(str(all_hosts[i]) + ": " + net['port'] + " is open")
        except TypeError as e:
            logging.critical(e)
            pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `pool.map(self.scan_network, all_hosts)` this calls `self.scan_network` passing in individual ips from `all_hosts`, but your code in `self.scan_network` assumes it gets a whole list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code based on @Alfred Rossi's answer (now including CSV output)

port_test.py

```
#! /usr/bin/python

# Import modules
import mysql.connector
import logging
import configparser
import coloredlogs
import os
import csv
from Client import Client

#logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s',level=logging.INFO)
coloredlogs.install(level='DEBUG')
coloredlogs.DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s -- %(message)s'


# read from the config file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
db=config['mysql']
net=config['network']
port = int(net['port'])
csvconfig=config['csv']
filepath = (csvconfig['filepath'])

try:
    os.remove(filepath)
    with open(filepath, 'w', newline='') as csvfileopen:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfileopen, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        spamwriter.writerow(["Client", "Location", "IP Address", "Open Port"])
except OSError as e:
    logging.debug(e)
    pass

# create the connection, connect, and setup the query
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=db['host'], user=db['user'], database=db['database'], password=db['password'])
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("select c.client_name as name, l.location_name as location, fw.net_cidr as cidr "
        "from firewalls fw "
            "left join clients c on c.id = fw.client_id "
            "left join locations l on l.id = fw.location_id "
                "where fw.net_cidr <> '' and c.active = '1' and fw.active = '1' "
                "order by c.client_name, l.location_name")

cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()

for (name, location, cidr) in results:
    client_obj = Client(name, location, cidr)
    net_addr = str(cidr)
    client_obj.display_results(net_addr)

# close the database connection

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Client.py

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

# Client.py
import logging
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import configparser
import coloredlogs
import ipaddress
import socket
import subprocess
import csv

# read from the config file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
net=config['network']
port = int(net['port'])
csvconfig=config['csv']
filepath = (csvconfig['filepath'])

class Client:
    def __init__(self, name, location, net_cidr):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.net_cidr = net_cidr


    def display_results(self, net_addr):
    # execute and display the results
            logging.info("{} -> {} --> {} ".format(self.name, self.location, self.net_cidr))
            try:
                ip_net = ipaddress.ip_network(net_addr)
                # Get all hosts on that network
                all_hosts = list(ip_net.hosts())

                # make a pool of workers
                pool = ThreadPool(16)

                # ping the cidrs in their own thread
                pool.map(self.scan_network, all_hosts)
                pool.close()
                pool.join()

            except ValueError as e:
                logging.warning(e)

    def scan_network(self, all_hosts):
        try:
                # For each IP address in the subnet, test to see if port 3389 is open
                sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                sock.settimeout(.25)
                result = sock.connect_ex((str(all_hosts),port))
                if result == 0:
                    with open(filepath, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
                        logging.info("\t\t\t" + str(all_hosts) + ": " + net['port'] + " is open")
                        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                        spamwriter.writerow([self.name, self.location, str(all_hosts), net['port']])
        except TypeError as e:
            logging.critical(e)
            pass
```

Comment: Perhaps, you should rename `scan_network()`'s parameter e.g., use `host` instead of misleading `all_hosts`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks. My focus was on getting this working before cleaning it up, I actually did make that change. I appreciate the advice!